# Existe um modo de não encher o HTML com diretivas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

Utilizando a diretiva `ng-click` para pegar um evento de clique em um *link* seria algo parecido com:

```
<a ng-click="call('home')" href="#" title="ir para homepage">Home</a>
```

Mas isto não seria a mesma coisa que o uso de `onclick="call('home')"`?

Uma boa prática no desenvolvimento web não é separar cada documento com a sua devida funcionalidade? Evitando aquele monte de CSS e JavaScript *inline*?

É possível, por exemplo, selecionar um elemento de forma semelhante ao conhecido `$('foo').on('click', function(){});` *i.e* conseguir acessar o elemento do arquivo JavaScript e sem encher o `HTML` de diretivas?

Por exemplo:

```
<a ng-model='abrir' href='#'>Abrir</a>
```

E no JS:

```
$scope.abrir.on('click', function(){
   call('foo');
});
```

Comment: Eu acho bacana poder ver no código da view a função de um botão, mas se não uso algo como AngularJS tenho que usar `$('foo').on('click', ...` para garantir que o evento esteja assinado depois de o componente ser reconstruído por uma requisição ajax. Informar na view a função do botão é como informar a fonte do valor de um campo, `{{pessoa.nome}}`. Isso não é o mesmo que misturar html e javascript no mesmo código. Você não está preocupado por exemplo com o código `<input class="btn-primary" type="submit"...`, está? Esse código tem o mesmo conceito que o seu `<a ng-click="call('home')"...`, não?

Comment: Também não vejo problemas, é mais uma dúvida de alguém que cansou de ouvir "separa o html do Js".

Comment: Boas práticas são mais ou menos assim: "Use UTF-8", "Não use Goto", "Não ponha return no meio da função", "Não use CSS no HTML", "Não deixe o if sem { }"... Sinceramente, você tem que usar cada coisa onde é melhor na hora que for melhor e pronto, desde que tenha conhecimento do que está fazendo. Boas práticas não suprem falta de conhecimento. Por outro lado, se você detém o conhecimento, não precisa mais das regrinhas enlatadas chamadas de "boas práticas", então no fim o que vale mesmo é entender como funciona, e fazer uma bela aplicação, enquanto o cara das boas práticas fica palpitando.

Comment: ótima resposmentário @Bacco.

Answer (score 1):

O `ng-click` é diferente do `onclick`. A diretiva do Angular utiliza [expressões da própria framework](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), ou seja, estão no contexto do escopo do Angular (que não é diretamente acessível pelo `onclick`).

E não, não há método do Angular que se comporte como os handlers do jQuery, mas você pode utilizá-lo paralelamente para executar expressões do escopo global.

Comment: Igual no sentido de "sujar" o HTML,  não que ambos se comportem da mesma forma. E sobre o uso paralelo, como seria?

Comment: Como qualquer outro código JavaScript, é só referenciá-lo no HTML. Você não vai ter acesso direto às variáveis e funções que estão no código do AngularJS. Para acessá-los, será preciso percorrer um caminhozinho (que às vezes, dependendo da estruturação do projeto, pode ser grande).

Answer (score 1):

O Angular vem para estender o HTML, em um primeiro momento você pode achar que está sujando, pra mim ele o torna mais declarativo, no modelo $('item').on('click', faz alguma coisa); lá no arquivo js, pode ser organizado para um programador mas para um designer está escondido porque no html não existe referencia ao código.